# TypeMock and mscorlib

Tags: typemock

Does anyone know if the current version of TypeMock can intercept mscorlib?

I'm looking for a replacement for Moles.  The main reason for this is due to legacy code.  I know of several mocking tools of course that can mock interface based code.  Like most places we have plenty of code we would like to bring under test that does not use injection of other methods.

Answer (score 4):

Typemock Isolator does have a limited ability to mock mscorlib types. There is [a list of mscorlib types they can mock in their online developer documentation](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/SupportedMscorlibTypes.html), but it doesn't appear to be updated with some of the latest release information.

Looking through release notes, a more complete list (to the best of my ability to put such a thing together) is:

- All interface types (as of [Isolator 3.7](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReleaseNotes37.html))
- Dynamic types (as of [Isolator 6.0](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReleaseNotes60.html))
- Extension methods on mscorlib types (as of [Isolator 4.2](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReleaseNotes42.html))
- DateTime (as of [Isolator 5.3](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReleaseNotes53.html))
- Environment (as of [Isolator 7.0](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReleaseNotes70.html))
- File (as of [Isolator 7.0](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReleaseNotes70.html))
- FileStream (as of [Isolator 7.0](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReleaseNotes70.html))
- StreamReader (as of [Isolator 7.0.7](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReleaseNotes707.html))
- X509Certificate (as of [Isolator 7.1.6](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReleaseNotes716.html))

Answer (score 0):

[TypeMock Isolator Essential](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) is designed for this task.